# How to display month fetched via JS in html email contents.?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

**code.gs**

```
function showMonth() {

  var recipient1 = 'user@gmail.com';
  var subject = "email subject";

  // send email using html page
  var emailTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('file');

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient1, subject,'',{'htmlBody': emailTemplate.evaluate().getContent(), 'cc': '', 'bcc': ''});

}
```

**file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body>

    <h2>My First Web Page</h2>

    <p>My First Paragraph.</p>

    <p id="displaymonth"> </p>

<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var mnth = getMonthDetails();
    function getMonthDetails() {
      switch (d.getMonth()) {
            case 9 : 
            return "October";
        break;
    }
  document.getElementById("displaymonth").innerHTML = "Current month is " + mnth;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in email:

```
My First Web Page
My First Paragraph.
```

I'm trying to get date and month in JS script tag and posting them to HTML content.
Later fetching the same HTML content using email template service of Google Apps Script and sending an email to user to show the current month.

When I run the code on other online editor like **jsfiddle.net**, it is showing the month details on the results page. However, I cannot get the expected result in the email upon running the code on Google Apps Script.

Let me know a way to fix my code to see the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: I think the simple answer is that Google apps script wasn’t designed to work that way for email html. There are other ways to get the job done. Use them. If I’m wrong I’m sure someone will correct me here soon and I can learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

**This way your email and your webapp get the same contents**

Most of the contents comes from a text file that's written in html. And then in the function `getContents()` I append the line with the month in it.  That function provides content to the doGet() and the sendEmail().

aq1.gs

```
function getContents() {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var file=folder.getFiles().next();//assume only one
  var contents=file.getBlob().getDataAsString()+Utilities.formatString('<p>This month is %s</p>',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMMM" ));//get content from file and append the date to it as a string
  return contents;
}

function sendEmail() {
  var recipient1 = 'recipient email';
  var subject = "Combining Email and Website Contents";
  var html=getContents();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient1, subject,'',{htmlBody:html});
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq5');
}

function launchDiaog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq5');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "My Dialog");
}
```

aq5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      console.log('Ready State Function');
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
        console.log(hl);
        $('#mydiv').html(hl);
      })
      .getContents();
    });
    console.log("My Code");
  </script>
  </head>  
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</html>
```

This is the contents of the ascii text file:

`<h2>My First Web Page</h2><p>My First Paragraph.</p><p>My second paragrah</p>`

But it could be anything upto 50MB

Comment: Is there a way that i can embed this in my html page contaniing multiple paragrapgh's . this specific line "The month is October" and post all the html content as an email. Instead of writing my entire html contents here like this --> Utilities.formatString('<h2>My First Web Page</h2><p>My First Paragraph.</p><p>This month is %s</p>'

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the date on the app script then passing it as a variable into your HTML file.
I don't think your client side js code will be executed by the Apps Script.